# HTML / Javascript - stop left /right arrow from changing dropdown menu choice

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I am creating a web form with a grid of inputs for creating objects in Django.

It seems that when the focus is on a drop down menu, the up and left arrows select the previous item  and right / down arrows select the next item.

I would like to use the left / right arrows to move focus left or right on the grid (a bit like excel does). Can I disable the left / right arrows from changing the menu choice, (while keeping the functionality for the up / down arrows)?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work in Firefox, only Chrome.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to work with firefox. I stumbled upon a issue with firefox not preventing the default behavior. Im not getting it perfect for FF :(

Comment: It seems to be working in the version I am using. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing default behavior of controls is sometimes frustrating for users. But other times the user expect it works like excel like in your case :)

You can do something like this:

```
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++){
    selects[i].addEventListener('keydown',function(e){    
        var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if(key == 37){
            var previousSibling = this.previousSibling;
            while(previousSibling && previousSibling.nodeType != 1) {
                previousSibling = previousSibling.previousSibling
            }
            previousSibling.focus();
            e.preventDefault();
        }else if(key === 39){
            var nextSibling = this.nextSibling;
            while(nextSibling && nextSibling.nodeType != 1) {
                nextSibling = nextSibling.nextSibling
            }
            nextSibling.focus();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    })
}
```

Key 37 = <kbd>←</kbd> and key 39 is <kbd>→</kbd>.
`e.preventDefault();` prevents the default behaviour of the key you pressed.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78C2U/2/)

Comment: I am trying to replace excel as a data upload tool, so I need to mimic the functionality they expect there.

Comment: I got more problems in firefox. I ended up using a hack to store the value, and set it back after the focus was moved to the next element. Not the nicest, but it does what I want it to.

Answer (score 2):

While [A1rPun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22321921/1185136) does what was asked, it does not work in Firefox. This is because of [this Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=291082), basically `event.preventDefault` doesn't prevent <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> on `<select>` nodes.

### Workaround

I made a workaround for this issue that can be used to improve A1rPun's answer to support Firefox.

```
function ensurePreventDefault(select) {
    var selectedIndex, scrollTop;
    function saveState() {
        selectedIndex = select.selectedIndex;
        scrollTop = select.scrollTop;
    }

    saveState();
    if (!select.multiple && !select.size) {
        select.addEventListener('change', saveState);
    }

    // use setTimeout to wait a frame and see if the selected index was changed
    setTimeout(function () {
        select.removeEventListener('change', saveState);
        if (select.selectedIndex !== selectedIndex) {
            // Damn you, Firefox!
            select.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
            select.scrollTop = scrollTop;
        }
    });
}
```

Short version: store the `selectedIndex` and restore it back a frame later.

Long version: store the `selectedIndex`, so that we can check later if it was changed by Firefox, using `setTimeout`. You'll also want to store these values on `'change'` event to fully support a dropdown. Also store `scrollTop` to prevent Firefox from scrolling inside a multi-select. These are rendered as lists, not as dropdowns, causing Firefox to scroll down or up when the selected index was changed. In case of a multi-select you do **not** want to listen to it's `'change'` event, this will have a reversed effect.

### Usage

You can use it like this:

```
.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    switch (event.which || event.keyCode) {
        case 37: // left arrow
        case 39: // right arrow
            event.preventDefault();
            ensurePreventDefault(this);
            break;
    }
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly18vLz4/)

This expands on A1rPun's JSFiddle.

Comment: apparently I downvoted you, but I have no recollection of that at all. And I don't even remember thinking about this answer. Must be a mistake. I'd gladly recall it, if you edit your answer slightly (that's not bending the rules I hope)

Answer (score 2):

[Ruud's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31206759/687667) works but if you look closely or if you have a lot of code running in the event, you'll see the select value changing the next element and back to the original one.

Here's a solution that works on Firefox, and looks cleaner to me. Untested in other browsers.

The trick is simply to set the select as disabled in the keydown event, then to reenable it on the next frame with a setTimeout. The anonymous function will not run until all the code in the event handler has been processed, assuring that the select is not reenabled too early.

```
mySelect.addEventListener('keydown', 
    function (event) {
        switch (event.which || event.keyCode || event.charCode) {
            case 33:
                this.disabled = true;
                setTimeout(function (elem) {elem.disabled = false;}, 0, this);
                break;

            case 34:
                this.disabled = true;
                setTimeout(function (elem) {elem.disabled = false;}, 0, this);
                break;
        }
    });
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLqvco8u/1/)

Comment: I see that this causes horrible flicker due to Opera actually repainting the elements immediately. None of the other stuff I've ever done triggers a repaint that fast, but here we have a pointless repaint interfering with a ludicrous fix to resolve a ludicrous bug in Firefox. I've given it an upvote anyway on the basis that I'm sure I can sniff out Firefox and target this fix … (same as I had to sniff out Opera to resolve an equally bizarre bug in that).

Comment: Edit: I see Firefox flickers too, but much less noticeably … Setting the background colour to (in this case) white after disabling it reduces the flicker further … and a CSS rule for this might reduce it further.

Comment: @DanielBeardsmore I do not see any flicker in Firefox. Are you on the latest release ? Do you also see this flicker on the JSFiddle ?

Comment: No I'm on (64-bit) Firefox ESR due to the Impending Add-on Doom (but Windows 10 1709 nonetheless). I didn't see the flicker at first, so it may be intermittent and may be video driver dependent, but yes it's there in the JSFiddle too. The flicker in the latest Opera was far worse (still only a few milliseconds, but more than in Firefox.) Basically you see the control dim to the disabled background colour and then return to white, which CSS can be used to control. --fake blank line-- (Bare key codes are a perfect example of the need for constants in JavaScript!!!)

Comment: @DanielBeardsmore Yes, it is probably video driver dependent. I'm on the latest Beta, and this somehow ugly fix works very well. It's ugly, but IMHO way less than the previous one by Ruud. I don't see any flicker on Chrome either, but then your workstation might just be a lot faster than mine. ;)

Answer (score 0):

IN regard to [the answer of Ruud Lenders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31206759/320502): works only if you have a single select in the form. If you have multiple select dropdowns then you can use the following version:

```
$(document).on('keydown', 'select', function(event) {
    var value = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    if ((event.which == 37 || event.which === 39)) {
        setTimeout(function (obj, val) {
            console.log(val)
                return function() {
                    obj.find('option[value="' + val + '"]').prop("selected", true)
                }
        }($(this), value), 0);
    }
});
```