# Disable keyboard input on <select> elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible to completely disable "built in" behavior where a select scrolls through items when arrow keys are pressed.

I tried

```
select.onkeydown = 
function(event)
{
 event.preventDefault();

 return false;
}
```

to no extent.

Interestingly, the above works for input, textarea, it even works for select itself as long it's select *multiple*

Something in the dropdown itself, the pulldown menu that appears and displays options, seems to be divorced from the event flow.

Even disabling keyboard input for the whole document

```
document.onkeydown =
function(event)
{
 event.preventDefault();
 event.stopPropagation();

 return false;
}
```

will disable keyboard input for all elements but NOT a select's dropdown.

Comment: Why would you want to disable this behavior, exactly? Totally removing a core interaction method users will *expect* to be there is teeing up a particularly poor UX. What about users who don’t or cannot use any input method *except* the keyboard?

Comment: Might need to modify for other arrow keys, but does this help answer your question? [HTML / Javascript - stop left /right arrow from changing dropdown menu choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321604/html-javascript-stop-left-right-arrow-from-changing-dropdown-menu-choice) (Note [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31206759/924299) from 2015 pertaining to Firefox.)

Comment: @showdev  doesn't seem to work for me (latest edge & chrome)

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in Chrome 116.0.5845.111. It seems the `keydown` event only fires when the <select> is focused, and it becomes unfocused when the <option> list is open. [Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/c5vsrf1a/).

Comment: One idea is to create a [custom drop-down](https://jsfiddle.net/shaiui/096sfbpL/) that excludes arrow key functionality. (Also see [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aiYi6cpn1M).)

Comment: @showdev that was already my measure of last resort. I was hoping not to have to go there..